# how to acces super variable $_POST in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

In my PDO statement I am using this following method to insert data to SQL:

```
//insert into database with a prepared statement
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (username,password,email,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :active)');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':username' => $_POST['username'],
                ':password' => $hashedpassword,
                ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                ':active' => $activasion
            ));
```

My problem is I get a warning message saying `Dont Access superglobal variable $_post directly`

And after google i found this solution `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'var_name')` instead of `$_POST['var_name']`

but this is for `PHP`

Is there any method for `PDO` how do i replace `$_POST` and `$_GET` in `PDO`?

Comment: have u tried to store the post values in a variable?

Comment: And is there any reason you can't just do `$var = $_POST['something']` like it suggests. Generally you don't want superglobals in any kind of database request as it *can* open up a can of worms.

Comment: soooo....what's stopping you from using `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'var_name')`...???

Comment: what is the down vote for? bad codding or bad question or bad coder? you should always down vote if the question is bad.

Comment: _"but this is for PHP"_ sureee...

Comment: PDO is a PHP system.  You can still use this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDO` is not a different language. It is a PHP extension used to connect and operate on a datasource.

You can use `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username')` without a problem in the code you have there.

```
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (username,password,email,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :active)');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':username' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username'),
            ':password' => $hashedpassword,
            ':email' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email'),
            ':active' => $activasion
        ));
```

This should work just fine, but I don't see why you can't just access `$_POST` directly, can't se a problem with it.

Comment: @lawrence Have you tried it??? I think you need to read up on what `PDO` is. You seem to think it is a different language.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username')` instead of `$_POST['username']` should work.

Comment: this method is `PHP` am asking about `PDO`

Comment: But PDO is PHP. It's PHP library for database access.

Answer (score -1):

use the $_POST values in a variable

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (username,password,email,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :active)');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':username' => $username,
            ':password' => $hashedpassword,
            ':email' => $email, 
            ':active' => $activasion
        ));
```

Comment: There is no real difference between this and the code he is already using? You're just temporarily saving it to a different variable.

Comment: @lshas - that's correct, there is no real difference in the values passed, the only difference is that PDO won't issue a warning for having superglobals in the execute statement, which after all was the question !

Comment: that code still leaves place for security vulnerabilitiy. And PDO doesn't warn just for fun ;)

Comment: @adeneo How does PDO know if the variable is accessed directly or not? the execute method only gets passed the resulting array anyways?

Comment: @lshas - I don't know, but as it's throwing the warning `Dont Access superglobals directly` it obviously knows.

Comment: @adeneo From what I can tell, the warning is coming from the IDE, not PHP, and not PDO. So this solution will not get rid of the warning.

Comment: this method is `PHP` am asking about `PDO`

Comment: @lshas - could be, I've never seen such a warning, but a search shows Netbeans has it. Doesn't matter who's throwing the warning, you don't want superglobals in the array anyway, so it's a good warning, and it's solved by moving the superglobal out of the execute method.